# Struggling with managing my eclipse workspace and what to do about syncing it between two machines

Tags: eclipse, git, ubuntu, synchronization, dropbox

I'm trying to sync my workspace with PC<---->Laptop. PC is windows, the laptop is ubuntu Linux. Both have 5.1 Mars eclipse version.

So far I've been using dropbox to sync in between but problems started occurring but managed to solve them. I was compiling classes with a newer version of java and the other eclipse didn't know what to do. Syncing with dropbox is really not an elegant way of doing this.

So now I'm trying out git, but so far I've been confused by it and how it works. I have managed to set the git plugin in the eclipse but not sure what to do next. The plugin is called EGit.

As far as I understand so far, it works like this? workspace--->local repo---->git repo? Then I would have to manually sync the code back on my laptop by entering the commands in terminal?

I already did push some stuff to my private repository, but that was on my laptop.

Is it possible to setup an easy way to sync the code? I know git is a good versioning system and a good way to keep the code updated? I'm a first year CS student and so far I don't have any complicated or large projects to manage with. I'm just looking for a nice way to sync the code. I guess having git setup is an ok way to go about it, but I'm overwhelmed by the features of git and not really grasping it.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a good idea to learn how to do it right. It's a better investment of your time than working on workarounds which only work in a certain situation or which are of limited use. Yes, you could use git for that. You do not really need the EGit plugin, just use the git command line, in my opinion that is easier. There are a bunch of great git tutorials out there. For the beginning the basic commands like git init, clone, pull, status, diff, add, commit, push are sufficient. You would need a central git repository, get a free GitHub account for that purpose.

Compiled classes should not be commited into your source repository. Add folders with any generated files to your .gitignore file.

Comment: thanks. some time ago i made a private repo, pushed stuff to it and i kindof left it as it was. i never commited changes to the local repo after that. since then lots of stuff changed. now what should i do?  just copy the whole folder and contents and merge with the local repo? and then commit and push?or should i just delete everything and make the local repo a copy of the local working folder?

Comment: Couldn't you just update the existing repo with your current source code, if that's for the same project? You could also start from scratch with git if you prefer. Make a backup in advance, just to make sure you do not lose something.

Comment: That's true. Also how should i go about it? can i just sync the whole workspace folder? what about the .metadata and .recommenders folders? are those ok to sync too?What classes get compiled in the workspace? dont i need classes if my code is in there?

Comment: Synchronize files you created yourself. Do not synchronize files created by your build tool or by your IDE. Do not synchronize generated files. Your code is in `.java` files, they must be synchronized. `.class` files are generated, do not sychronize them.

Comment: i see, thanks. last thing im trying to do is. do i really have to copy my workspace everytime into the local repository with every change? could i just use the local repo as the eclipse workspace or is that just bound to cause problems? how would i then automate the copying and such?

Comment: For each project you have one local repo. This is the same folder Eclipse uses for the project. No local copying is necessary.